# Selecting only one row for variable that isn't unique

Tags: mysql

I want to select only one row with the Id 'productId', I am now displaying all three rows with 'productId' of 3, how can I only display 1 row?

[image]

```
      $sql = "SELECT * from Product
      inner join OrderItems ON Product.productId = OrderItems.productId";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you decide which of the 3 rows you want? That's the key to solving this.

Comment: If you want to randomly pick one of them, put 'LIMIT 1' at the end of your SQL Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the nudge from Joe, this works!

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Product
inner join OrderItems ON Product.productId = OrderItems.productId where Product.size = OrderItems.size and Product.color = OrderItems.colors";
```

Comment: Happy to nudge. ;-)